# Timeout a script with stdin

Tags: bash, timeout

I need something like this:

```
timeout -k 4 cat file | myscript.sh
```

but i get this error:

```
timeout: invalid time interval ‘cat’
Try 'timeout --help' for more information.
```

I want to pass stdin to myscript.sh, and kill it after 4s of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon reading the output of `timeout --help` (as suggested by the output in your question), I found that you are not using the proper arguments for the `timeout` command.

The format of the command is: `timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...`

And the `-k` option also takes a `DURATION` argument. So when using `-k`,there must be **two** `DURATION` arguments.

So a proper format could be: `timeout -k 6 4 cat file | myscript.sh`

It is not going to change much though. `cat` doesn't block the `TERM` signal, so sending a `KILL` signal isn't necessary. And even if you do kill `cat`, that is no guarantee that the script terminates. It just means the script will get `EOF`, in case it tries to read any more from `stdin`.

You are probably better off putting a timeout on the script instead of the `cat` command.

Comment: Thanks! Found the answer like 5 mins before yours, but really thanks anyway! Bytheway i wanted to append the timeout on the script, to do that i used timeout -k 2 2 bash -c "cat file | script.sh"

Comment: i don't see this two args for `-k` in the docs. what are the two args?

Comment: @chovy `-k 6` will send `SIGKILL` after 6 seconds.

Comment: right. that's 1 arg.